# How can I find the center of gravity of a hollow spherical cap?

Tags: spherical-geometry

I am looking to find the center of gravity for a hollow spherical cap. Could I use that point as the point at which the entire mass of the spherical cap is for newtonian gravity problems?

Comment: When you find out, let this guy know: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380860/center-of-gravity-of-a-hollow-or-solid-semi-sphere